# Get value from cell in Shiny DataTable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, expss

I have this DataTable in Shiny and I would like to get the value from the first column in a variable textbox when I click an row.

[image: Screenshot here]

So in this case as seen in the screenshot, when I click this row, I would like to get `Factuur Factuur` in the place where now is `Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`.
I managed to get the row number:

> UI:
>   `p(verbatimTextOutput('chauffeurdetails'))`
>
> Server:
>   `output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
>        chauffeurdetail = input$results_rows_selected
>     })`

Anyone thought how I could get the value from the first column instead of only the row number?

Whole R code:

```
# install packages if needed
if (!require("DT")) install.packages("DT")
if (!require("tidyr")) install.packages("tidyr")
if (!require("dplyr")) install.packages("dplyr")
if (!require("readxl")) install.packages("readxl")
if (!require("shiny")) install.packages("shiny")
if (!require("expss")) install.packages("expss")

# activate packages
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
library("readxl")
library("DT")
library("shiny")
library("expss")

# Lees MI bestand
MIinport <- read_excel("~/Documents/MI.xlsx", col_types = c("skip", "skip", "text", "skip", "text", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "text", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "text","skip",  "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "text","skip",  "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip"))
# Hernoem kolommen
MIinport <- unite(MIinport, KlantRef, Klant, Referentie, sep=" | ", remove = TRUE)
colnames(MIinport)<- c("Chauffeur", "Kenteken", "Klant", "ARDNK")
# Filter locatiewerk
MIinport <- subset(MIinport, is.na(MIinport$Kenteken))
MIinport$Kenteken <- NULL

DNK <- subset(MIinport, ARDNK == "DNK")
DNK$ARDNK <- NULL
AR <- subset(MIinport, ARDNK == "AR")
AR$ARDNK <- NULL

DNKfreq1 <- ftable(DNK$Chauffeur, DNK$Klant, dnn = c("Chauffeur", "Klant"))
DNKfreq2 <- as.data.frame(DNKfreq1)
DNKdata <- subset(DNKfreq2, Freq>0)
colnames(DNKdata)<- c("Chauffeur", "Klant", "Aantal")
list.DNKklanten <- as.list(unique(sort(DNKdata$Klant)))

ARfreq1 <- ftable(AR$Chauffeur, AR$Klant, dnn = c("Chauffeur", "Klant"))
ARfreq2 <- as.data.frame(ARfreq1)
ARdata <- subset(ARfreq2, Freq>0)
colnames(ARdata)<- c("Chauffeur", "Klant", "Aantal")
list.ARklanten <- as.list(unique(sort(ARdata$Klant)))

# Onderscheid studenten - FALSE = Student | TRUE = Senior
ARdata$Student <- as.numeric(grepl('[.]', ARdata$Chauffeur))
ARstudent <- subset(ARdata, Student == 0)
ARstudent$Student <- NULL
ARdata$Student <- NULL


# App
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  p (""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      div(
      h3("Zoek instellingen"),
      uiOutput("chooselist"),
      checkboxInput("StudentOption", label = "Alleen studenten", value = FALSE),
      radioButtons("ARofDNK", label = "AR of DNK", choices = c("AR", "DNK"), selected = "AR", inline = TRUE)
    ),
    div(tags$hr(),
        h3("Chauffeur details"),
        p(textOutput('chauffeurdetails')))),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
# update datatable
output$chooselist <- renderUI({ 
  if (input$ARofDNK == "AR"){
    tagList(
    selectInput("select", "Selecteer een klant", choices = c(" ", list.ARklanten))
    )
  } else {
    tagList(
    selectInput("select", "Selecteer een klant", choices = c(" ", list.DNKklanten))
    )
  }
  })
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$ARofDNK })

  SelectedKlant <- reactive({
    if (input$StudentOption == TRUE & input$ARofDNK == "AR") {
      a <- subset(ARstudent, (ARstudent$Klant == input$select))
      return(a)
    } 
    else if (input$StudentOption == FALSE & input$ARofDNK == "AR") {
      a <- subset(ARdata, (ARdata$Klant == input$select))
      return(a)
    } else if (input$ARofDNK == "DNK"){
      a <- subset(DNKdata, (DNKdata$Klant == input$select))
      return(a)
    }
})

  output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(SelectedKlant(), options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = 'tip', order = list(2,'desc')), rownames = FALSE, width = 500, elementId = "results", colnames=c('Naam', 'Locatie', 'Aantal'), selection = 'single')

#  output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
#    SelectedKlant()[input$results_rows_selected,1]
#  })

  output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
    req(length(input$results_rows_selected)>0)
    SelectedKlant()[input$results_rows_selected,1]
  })  

# output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
#     chauffeurdetail = input$results_rows_selected
# })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  session$on

  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Edit:
Example data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjxusxcan0ps1s3/Input%20Test.xlsx?dl=0
Those data contains privacy sensitive information, so I created a small replacement.

Comment: Can you post the code that is giving the error?

Comment: @SBista The code above is working and shows the row number.

Comment: @SBista I added the whole shiny code

Comment: Assuming `ARstudent` is your dataset you can try `ARstudent[input$results_rows_selected,1]`

Comment: @SBista, when I change this Server part to 
output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
  SelectedKlant[input$results_rows_selected,1]
})
I get that error in the screenshot
(SelectedKlant = dataframe for my datatable)

Comment: Could you provide a sample data so I could debug further?

Comment: Hi @SBista I added the sample data today. I had to remove the privacy sensitive information, but I hope you can work with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
  SelectedKlant()[input$results_rows_selected,1]
})`

Should solve it.

Your last problem was the classic `stringAsFactor` and that the first column was a factor and there for we need to convert it to character with `as.character()`

here is a working version of the server code

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # update datatable
  output$chooselist <- renderUI({ 
    if (input$ARofDNK == "AR"){
      tagList(
        selectInput("select", "Selecteer een klant", choices = c(" ", list.ARklanten))
      )
    } else {
      tagList(
        selectInput("select", "Selecteer een klant", choices = c(" ", list.DNKklanten))
      )
    }
  })
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$ARofDNK })

  SelectedKlant <- reactive({
    if (input$StudentOption == TRUE & input$ARofDNK == "AR") {
      a <- subset(ARstudent, (ARstudent$Klant == input$select))
      return(a)
    } 
    else if (input$StudentOption == FALSE & input$ARofDNK == "AR") {
      a <- subset(ARdata, (ARdata$Klant == input$select))
      return(a)
    } else if (input$ARofDNK == "DNK"){
      a <- subset(DNKdata, (DNKdata$Klant == input$select))
      return(a)
    }
  })

  output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(SelectedKlant(), options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = 'tip', order = list(2,'desc')), rownames = TRUE, width = 500, elementId = "results", colnames=c('Naam', 'Locatie', 'Aantal'), selection = 'single')

  #  output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
  #    SelectedKlant()[input$results_rows_selected,1]
  #  })

  output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
    req(length(input$results_rows_selected)>0)
    as.character(SelectedKlant()[input$results_rows_selected,1])
  })  

  # output$chauffeurdetails = renderText ({
  #     chauffeurdetail = input$results_rows_selected
  # })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  session$on

}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Now, I got a random number. Besides your adjustments, I changed `verbatimTextOutput` in the UI to `TextOutput`, otherwise it didn't work at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @George I added a working example. If this doesn't work for you we need more information and preferbly some sample data that you are working with. I small sample sshould be enougth.

Comment: @Berlin Baron, I tried, but unfortunately, I still receive a number as reaction. On request, I posted a sample document on the starting post. I hope you can reproduce what I see. I also dropped the whole code instead, which helps you understand.

Comment: @George I have fixed it - it was a classic `strinAsFactor` problem