# Get cell values from selected datatable row in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a datatable output in shiny app

```
output$riskregDT <- renderDT(
DT::datatable(riskregDT, options = list(pageLength = 25), selection=list(mode="single", target="row))
```

[image: datatable output]

Now when a user selects a row I need to get the values for that row and use these values in calculations.

For example, I need to get the value of the loss magnitude minimum of the selected row

I tried the following but not working:

```
        loss_event_frequency_min_DT <- as.numeric(input$riskregDT_rows_selected,1,1)
        loss_event_frequency_likely_DT <- as.numeric(input$riskregDT_rows_selected,3,3)
        loss_event_frequency_max_DT <- as.numeric(input$riskregDT_rows_selected,2
```

Any idea what I can do thanks

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846335/get-value-from-cell-in-shiny-datatable

Comment: yeah still can't get it to work